# Disable "Advanced ..." in workflow status menu in Plone

Tags: plone

I want to disable the "Advanced ..." (content_status_history) link in the workflow status menu for other roles except Managers and Site Administrators.  Is there a permission that I can use to do this? Or is this link's permission coupled with the presence of a transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link's presence is coupled to there being a workflow transition. The form it links to offers additional options to set for the transitions that are available on the current object. There is no permission that controls it's presence; the menu item is hardcoded.

From the [`plone.app.contentmenu.menu` source](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contentmenu/blob/6252354d07e8946cced6effbd0a7a3957d202a60/plone/app/contentmenu/menu.py#L634):

```py
    if len(results) > 0:
        results.append({ 'title'        : _(u'label_advanced', default=u'Advanced...'),
                         'description'  : '',
                         'action'       : url + '/content_status_history',
                         'selected'     : False,
                         'icon'         : None,
                         'extra'        : {'id': 'advanced', 'separator': 'actionSeparator', 'class': 'kssIgnore'},
                         'submenu'      : None,
                        })
```

To provide your own implementation (perhaps using a subclass that *removes* the last option again if certain conditions are met), you'd have to use an [`override`](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/zcml.html#overrides) to redefine the `browser:menu` registration.

In your `overrides.zcml` you'd have to point to your own implementation using the following `browser:menu` declaration:

```xml
  <browser:menu
    id="plone_contentmenu_workflow"
    title="The 'workflow' menu - allows the user to execute workflow transitions"
    class=".yourmodule.YourWorkflowMenu"
    />
```

then in `yourmodule.py` create a `YourWorkflowMenu` class, something like:

```py
from plone.app.contentmenu.menu import WorkflowMenu

class YourWorkflowMenu(WorkflowMenu):
    def getMenuItems(self, context, request):
        results = super(YourWorkflowMenu, self).getMenuItems(context, request)
        if len(results) > 0 and someothercondition:
            # Remove status history menu item ('Advanced...')
            results = [r for r in results
                if not r['action'].endswith('/content_status_history')]
        return results
```

Comment: I was expecting a shorter way to do it with permissions.  But this works.

Comment: Fantastic answer, works like a charm on Plone 4.2. I would +100 if I could.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to hide the menu item by adding

```
a#advanced {
   display: none;
}
```

to your styles.

That's a pragmatic solution compared the bloated former clean solution.

Comment: This hides the menu, but doesn't disable it from someone who can observe or guess its URL. Whether that's a problem depends on the situation.

Comment: Right...however the underlaying security machinery still applies here.

Comment: This suggestion was already obvious to me.  But I did not just want to just hide it but also to disable it.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the difference. Even if you remove the menu item, the view for performing the action is still present regardless. This is the easiest and best solution.

Comment: Additionally, the form will be shown, too, if you go via the Contents-Tab, mark an article and hit the 'Change-state'-button. To really disable that for everyone but managers, you'd also have to customize at least the content_status_history-template. I don't get the usecase, because this is a batch-functionality, rather than a matter of access, ain't it?